# Adding pull down screen in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, drop-down-menu

I would like to know if its possible to create a pull down screen(not splash screen or drop down list) which when clicked on a small triangle like component allows the user to pull it down and thereby open a new screen or menu list.

I have noticed this kind of feature on iphone and on websites too.But i am unsure whether anything as such can be done for a blackberry application.Anyone with any knowledge of such programming component please aid a suggestion.Thanks.

Comment: I wonder what makes people cast a vote down for no sane reason.Its so discouraging for amateur developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For BB 5.0 and later, have a look at the `EyelidFieldManager` control for the pull-down effect.  It doesn't have the triangle, though. I've been trying to figure out that one myself without much luck.

Comment: Thanks.I never knew it was there in the samples itself.